# The result of \sTrue is drawn with left margin in struktex structured chart

Tags: miktex, struktex

I am using `\usepackage{struktex}` to draw structure charts. Below you see one of my examples. In my case the result of `\sTrue` is drawn with a very large left margin an the result of `\sFalse` with a very large right margin. How can I align the results on the left and respectively right border?

```
\begin{struktogramm}(80,50)
    \ifthenelse[15]{3}{3}{condition}{\footnotesize{\sTrue}}{\footnotesize{\sFalse}}
        \assign[15]{\footnotesize{Block 1}}
    \change
        \assign[15]{\footnotesize{Block 2}}
    \ifend
    
\end{struktogramm}
```

Comment: Use `\usepackage[outer]{struktex}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outer` option is your friend.

If you want to apply `\footnotesize` to every cell, just issue it at the beginning. Note also that it's not a command taking an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  pict2e,
  %verification,
  outer
]{struktex}

\begin{document}

\begin{struktogramm}(80,50)
    \footnotesize
    \ifthenelse[15]{1}{1}{condition}{\sTrue}{\sFalse}
        \assign[15]{Block 1}
    \change
        \assign[15]{Block 2}
    \ifend
\end{struktogramm}

\end{document}
```

[image]